# How to properly clear database using fixtures when testing with pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest, factory-boy

I have a test database. Let's assume there are three tables created in there:

```
create table users (
    id serial constraint users_pkey primary key,
    name text not null
);
create table roles (
    id serial constraint roles_pkey primary key,
    name text not null
);
create table users_roles (
    user_id int constraint users_roles_users_fkey references users(id),
    role_id int constraint users_roles_roles_fkey references roles(id)
);
```

Every test starts with filling the database with data using factory_boy factories. Typical test looks like this:

```
def test_get_user_roles(api_client):
    user = UserFactory.create(id=1)
    role = RolesFactory.create(id=1)
    users_roles = UsersRolesFactory.create(user_id=1, role_id=1)
    response = api_client.get(f"/users/{user.id}/roles")
    assert ...
```

I could clear table using @pytest.mark.usefixtures("clear_users_roles", "clear_users", "clear_roles"), where "clear_users_roles", "clear_users", "clear_roles" are fixtures that obviously clear tables if there were no relationships between tables. 
But in the example above there are relationships (foreign keys) between table users_roles and user and between users_roles and roles and the problem is that fixtures run out of order. 
So when I run my tests I get an integrity error, because, for example, fixture "clear_users" was executed before "clear_users_roles" and my RDBMS cannot delete a record because the record still  references to table "users". Is there a proper way to run fixtures in specific order? Or may be there are some patterns/best practices for case like this?

Comment: Could you use something like Docker to bring up and shut down your db instance?

Comment: Could you detail the ORM layer you're using? Most of those come with helpers to manage transactions around test cases.

Comment: It seems like you just need to add a dependency on the "clear_users_roles" fixture from the "clear_users" and "clear_roles" fixtures to guarantee the execution ordering.  In pytest that's done just by adding the dependency as a parameter to the fixture function.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using teardown code in your fixtures with yield keyword?

Example from [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code):

```
# content of conftest.py

import smtplib
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def smtp_connection():
    smtp_connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, timeout=5)
    yield smtp_connection  # provide the fixture value
    print("teardown smtp")
    smtp_connection.close()
```

Comment: Yes, I have. The thing is, I have many different tests for different use cases. So I cannot use one teardown fixture for all of tests because it seem kind of redundant to execute clean up queries for tables that weren't used in particular test. The best solution for me would be use particular teardown fixtures on specific tests. For example, if I create User and Role in test, I want to specify explicitly that afterwards I need to delete data only from tables "users" and "roles".

Comment: @IvanDenisovich you can apply fixtures to single tests by marking tests with `@pytest.mark.usefixtures('myfixturename')`